# HRESULT 0x80131047 exception in Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 express when debug

Tags: vb.net

i get a HRESULT 0x80131047 exception in Microsoft Visual Basic 2008 express when debug my application. this happens whenever i click "start debugging" and it doesn't matter what application i load. this is a brand new vista x64 bit machine with a fresh install of VB2008 express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This MSDN forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/02be3d7e-cff5-47a7-a00a-1c5ebfcb47a7) says that you need to take "special" characters such as slashes, commas, or apostrophes out of your assembly name to avoid that error.

If that doesn't fix it, another suggestion there is to uncheck "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process" in the Debug tab.

Answer (score 1):

It may not necessarily be *special character* as in my case...

This was a hard issue to troubleshoot as there may be many variables leading non-functioning assemblies.

So I was working on an Outlook Add-In 2010 targeting the 32-bit version of Office. Everything was working fine until one day out of the blues, the add-in wouldn't load anymore and I was presented with error "**HRESULT: 0x80131047**". After searching almost half-a-day I found a nice article:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2007/05/06/2457576.aspx

I tried adding the assembly to the global cache but was unable to. Luckily, I had an almost identical project which ran just fine and I had already done comparison checks but all references and settings were the same, but on this pass I found something different ... as it turned out the platform target CPU was set to 64-bit so I changed it to "**Any**" and voila'! - problem fixed!

I was then able to run the project in Debug mode, Outlook launched and loaded with Add-in without a hitch.